# how to loop cut a mesh that doesn't have clear edge flow

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, shortcut, loop

i have mesh like this[image]

and i need to cut it like this[image]

but i can't because as you can see the mesh have a crazy topology

Answer (score 1):

In Edit mode with your entire mesh selected, under the Mesh menu  go to "Clean Up" and click "Limited Dissolve" this should remove the triangulation on the quads and make edge loop cutting work as expected.

Comment: Which, to that, I would add that your UV sphere shouldn’t be subdivided into triangles like that in the first place. Clearly you must have had a reason to think it was necessary, but just wanted to point out it is the wrong way to go about accomplishing your mesh (short of extremely niche circumstances I suppose).

Comment: thank you for your answer Chris i will try it out but isn't better to use tris to quads command in face drop down i found it from a video.

Comment: @John, this was not my original mesh that has the problem on it. the original mesh is a cloth that have so much triangles its not a simple sphere

Comment: @YonalJayasinghe A quad is already 2 tris when modeling quads are better to work with and lead to cleaner topology. Tris can be added later for specific reasons like optimizing a mesh for a game model, terminating an edge loop or maybe fixing a shading issue with  planar N-gon surface that you would get from things like booleans. If your actual mesh is a cloth you can try using the triangulate modifier on it instead.